How do I make it so a particle is invisible to a specific player tag?
Me and a friend are making a Dead by Daylight Minecraft map and we need a certain particle to only appear to players with the tag survivor and and not to those with the tag killer. How would we accomplish this?

For Minecraft commands questions, please see our guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.

Using a vanilla (or vanilla-like) server, you cannot do this on bedrock. Particles are visible to to everyone in the particle render radius.
In minecraft-java-edition, the /particle command can take an optional viewers argument, but this is exclusive to that version.
